# How can an angular controller access HTML without a model or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I am working with some legacy code and am confused about the way it's set up. I've only ever known of enabling communication between HTML and JS with classes, id's, elements, etc, when using jquery or an ng-model with angular.

in this bit of code, though, there is a controller that calls to a service immediately on page load:

```
//someController.js
someService.getStuff().then(function (result) {
            $scope.stuffToDisplay= result;
        });

//someService.js
var getStuff = function () {
            return $http.get('http://www.someapi.com/?userInput=' + userInput).then(function (result) {// where did the variable "userInput" come from?
                return result.data;
            });
        }
```

as can be seen above. Note that in the definition of `getStuff`, there are no arguments accepted that would account for `userInput`. Also there are no variables elsewhere defined in "someService.js" that are called `userInput`.

There is however, in  the HTML an input field, with `id='userInput'` and `ng-model='userInput'`. That being said, there is NO scope variable anywhere in the controller called `userInput`, and when i take the model off of the input element, nothing breaks. HOWEVER (super bizarre) when I remove the `id='userInput'`, I get

> ReferenceError: userInput is not defined

And when I replace `id='userInput'`, set a breakpoint on `getStuff`, and log `userInput` to the console, it prints out the entire HTML input element! What am I missing? I did not know this was possible. It clearly is, but how??

Comment: is there a userInput in the ng-app scope?

Comment: Maybe it's because you can access input by id, like in old school IE 6? See  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/9yw1ttg5/).

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko what is this wizardry??! i never knew of such a thing! not saying much because i've only been at this just coming up on a year, but i've not come across this before! i think that's what's happening, though... i don't get it, though.

Comment: More about this on [w3c](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object). If you can, it is better to rewrite the code to use `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()`. Even **better**, pass an argument `userInput` to a function `getStuff()`.

Comment: Exactly what I'm in the process of doing at this very moment. Thanks for your help @StepanKasyanenko!